# In which tense to use the verb "rent"?

Tags: tense

If someone's tenancy hasn't elapsed yet, how to describe the situation: he rented/is renting/rents a room?

If someone rented out a room, does it mean that his tenant is using the room or has finished using it and vacated it?

Comment: If your tenant is still in residence, you "rent out a room." The tenant can say " I rent a room." But if you "rented out a room" the meaning is unclear without more context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a current tenancy then either "he is renting..." or "he rents..." are fine.

If you say "Charles rented out a room...* it would suggest that the rental has ceased, but:

you need to be a careful here - because the verbs "to rent", and "to rent out" CAN apply both to a continuing situation as well as to the initial act of renting or renting out.

e.g "I rented out my room before I went away..." - the tenancy may still be continuing, or it could have ceased. All it tells us is that they rented out the room.